# javascript function execution

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to understand the function call in this scenario, How does `state` get resolved to viewFunc in addView function definition ( hooks between these ) and takes defaultData as function argument ?

```
var defaultData = {

  property: [
    {
      name: 'Adam',
      type: 'javascript'
    },
    {
      name: 'Tom',
      type: 'Typescript'
    }
  ]
};

function addView(viewFunc){
  console.log(" 1. Step I");
  viewFunc(defaultData);
  console.log(" 2. Step III ");
}

addView((state)=>{
  console.log(" 3. Step II & lenght of data set : "+state.property.length);
})
```

Output:

```
1. Step I
3. Step II & lenght of data set : 2
2. Step III
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question (or why you are unsure). *You* are passing `defaultData` to the callback: `viewFunc(defaultData);`. That's how it gets its value. It's the same as with any other function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions can be passed as parameters to other functions. This is what you are doing when calling `addView`: you create an anonymous function and pass it to the `addView` function.

The `viewFunc` variable now contains a reference to the anonymous function. Like any other function reference, you can call it with arguments. This is what you doing when you pass a reference to the `defaultData` object to the function that was passed into the `addView` function.

Function references that are passed as arguments to other functions or returned from another function are called [first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function).

Comment: thanks for the great explanation, However anonymous function doesn't take any argument but the reference to anonymous function (`viewFunc`) does but it doesn't throw any exception ?

Comment: What do you mean? The anonymous function *does* take an argument, which you named `state`. Your code is valid and correct.

Comment: my bad, I was overthinking. Thank you very much.